# How to execute a shell script with selected files/folders in finder?

Tags: macos, terminal, script, finder

I'm coming from Linux where it's easy to run a script against a set of files in nautilus or dolphin, but I was kind of surprised to see that this isn't easy in OSX.

Preferably, I would love to be able to ctrl-click on some selection in finder, choose my script, and have a terminal window pop up to show progress or any user interaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest, built-in way to do this is to just drag the items from *Finder* to a *Terminal* window. When you drop them, *Terminal* will “type” their (escaped) pathnames. You can then use your shell's command line editing to enter the rest of the command. Or if you are thinking ahead, you can type the command first then drag in the items.

The “drag first” version:

1. Select and drag some *Finder* items to a *Terminal* window that is showing a shell prompt. *Terminal* will insert the (escaped) pathnames.
2. Type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (go to the beginning of the line; ⌃A is the default, but varies by shell/configuration).
3. Type your command and a space (it will be inserted before the pathnames).

The “thinking ahead” version:

1. In any order, do both:

   - In a *Terminal* window, type the initial part of your command and space (everything except the pathnames).
   - Select some items in *Finder*.
2. Drag the selected items from *Finder* to the *Terminal* window where you typed the command.
3. Activate the *Terminal* window and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

---

You can (as other answers have indicated) turn to AppleScript or Automator if you need more a more automated solution. Since the extra “moving parts” can add some complexity to the solution, you will have to weigh the benefits of the above process (manual, but flexible) against the the complexity of implementing one or more of the automated solutions.

Some of the automation possibilities include:

- an AppleScript droplet application
- a plain AppleScript program launched by the built-in script menu or other launcher

  - get pathnames from *Finder*'s selection
- an Automator workflow, application, or *Finder* plug-in
- an executable `.command` file (usually a shell script; open in *Finder* to run it in *Terminal*)

  - get pathnames from *Finder*'s selection (via *osascript*)
- some third-party tool that already provides the functionality you need

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is a way to do this directly.  You can build an "Automator" application that will do some of what you are seeking. This shows what the Automator stack would look like:

[image]

Save the result as an Application, then in the finder select the files, right-click and select "Open with" then pick your application.  (You may need to select "Other..." at the bottom of the application list.)

You don't get to interact with the script with this method, but you can loop over the files to perform some shell script.

Comment: It's even easier if you drag the files over the application icon, and drop them.

Answer (score 8):

**Services** are how [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) handles this sort of thing.

Under the Application Menu (in this case 'Finder') there is (almost) always a `Services` menu option which will provide Services that apply to the current Application *and* its current state. Typically the state is what type of object is selected (text, files/folders, etc).

They can be enabled, disabled, and assigned keyboard shortcuts in the System Preferences panel that only makes sense for the last of those three, `Keyboard`.

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

**To make a Service that applies a shell script to files/folders in Finder:**

Launch [automator](/questions/tagged/automator) and make a new `Service` type document.

[image: New Service]

- set the type of object the Service applies to (`files or folders`)
- set the Application in which the Service is available ([finder](/questions/tagged/finder))

  - Alternatively there is a `Get Selected Finder Items` action.
- add an action of `Run Shell Script`
- decide if you want the input as arguments or [stdin](/questions/tagged/stdin)

It should look something like this:

[image: example shell script]

[automator](/questions/tagged/automator) will automatically place it in your `~/Library/Services` folder when you save which will make it available (almost) immediately via the `Application -> Services` menu, or the contextual (right click) menu.

[image: test folders]

[image: resulting TextEdit document]

Comment: In hindsight I should have linked [How create an OS X service that passes a file's path to a shell script?](http://superuser.com/questions/373284/) which has [a very similar answer](http://superuser.com/a/373322/12538).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers above, I built this thingy

https://github.com/commonpike/DropShell

Basicly an applescript app that calls a shellfile located in the app with the dropped files as arguments. You can modify the shell script as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on commonpike's answer, I have created a AppleScript, that redirects all files dropped onto it, to a shell script with the matching name. Simply save as application from within Apple's ScriptEditor and rename as script.app to match your script.sh
https://github.com/PHolker/scripts/blob/master/DropScript.scpt

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X, the preferred script language is Applescript. You can create a droplet (a script that will do something when you drop some files over its icon), place the script (which can be saved as application) icon over the desktop, and drag and drop the files you want to pass to the script.

As alternative, you can use folder actions. It is possible to associate a script Applescript to a folder that will be executed all the times some files (or directories) are dropped over the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wanting to do that too, however unlike the solutions above, I wanted to produce quoted parameters for a shell script. Those other methods are fine, but they're kind of like suggesting "just command-v into terminal" when what you really want is `pbpaste`.

I wanted to make a shell function I can use in my scripts that expanded to file parameters for each Finder selection. I use the fish shell and this seems to work somewhat:

```
function selection
    osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set s to the selection as alias list" -e "repeat with f in s" -e "set contents of f to POSIX path of f" -e "end repeat" -e "set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed" -e "s as string"
end
```

Used (again in the fish shell) like `convert-video (selection)`.

In a bash function, it might need to quote the output with something like `| tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 printf "%q" {}` on the end of that osascript command, not sure.

*(note: everything i know about advanced applescript & shell scripting i re-learned in the past 2 hours and will forget by tomorrow)*

Comment: Was trying to do this in bash recently, failed, asked on here https://superuser.com/questions/1353966, got answers that indicate: no, not possible :^( Bash you lose, gonna switch to fish shell on my work Mac also.

Note that I do use the drag-to-finder trick mentioned by Chris Johnsen above, quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since discovering [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) (which I highly recommend), I've been looking for a way to go all-in on it and rid myself of Automator. So I needed to have a way to pass the selected Finder items as parameters to the shell.

For that, I created a handler in my Applescript library `Handlers.scpt` in `~/Library/Script Libraries` which returns the selection as POSIX or HFS paths, depending on the passed boolean.

```
on getselection(hfs as boolean)
    set text item delimiters to linefeed
    tell application "Finder" to set s to text items of (selection as text)
    if hfs then return s
    repeat with i in s
        set contents of i to POSIX path of i
    end repeat
    return s as text
end getselection
```

From my Bash script, I read the result of the handler to an array. The script exits when the first element in the array is empty.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
mapfile -t i < <(osascript -e 'tell script "Handlers" to getselection(0)')
[[ $i ]] || exit 0

whatever-command "${i[@]}"
```