# How create an OS X service that passes a file's path to a shell script?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, automator

I have a shell script that takes two arguments:

- full file path
- file name

How can I use Automator to add a context menu entry to Finder to run the shell script with a chosen file path and file name as arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select to create a *Service* in Automator that receives *selected files and folders* as input in *Finder* only. Add the *Run Shell Script* action and *pass input as arguments*.

The arguments you receive are the full Unix paths of the selected files and folders. Using `growlnotify`, part of [Growl](http://growl.info/) for demonstration purposes:

> [image]

Growl message as a result of running it on a file:

> [image]

The command appears in the context menu of a file or folder in Finder. If there are too many applicable *Services*, they are grouped into a submenu *Services*.

> [image]

---

If your script requires *both* the full file path, and the *file name*, you can do something like the following, first extracting the file name from the full path:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    name="$( basename $f )"
    /usr/local/bin/growlnotify "$name" -m "$f"
done
```

You can see that the file name is used as title, while the path is used as message in Growl:

> [image]

---

If you need to query for additional input, you can execute a short AppleScript to do that. The following is a complete shell script (like the `growlnotify` above) that queries for input, and renames the selected file to that new name. I did not include error handling and such, e.g. adding colons and slashes to the new file name will likely break the script.

```
    # repeat for every file in selection
for f in "$@"
do
    # capture input of a simple dialog in AppleScript
    OUT=$( osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to text returned of (display dialog \"New Name of $f:\" default answer \"\")" )
    # if the user canceled, skip to the next file
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] || continue
    # old file name is the loop variable
    OLD="$f"
    # new file name is the same directory, plus the user's input
    NEW="$( dirname "$OLD" )/$OUT"
    # print a message announcing the rename
    /usr/local/bin/growlnotify "Renaming…" -m "$OLD to $NEW"
    # perform the actual rename
    mv "$OLD" "$NEW"
done
```

Screenshot of a sample rename action announced via `growlnotify`:

> [image]

Comment: It worked like magic. thanks!!! Also, I use growlnotifier for displaying results of the operation. One question, where are the services stored? It didn't prompt a location. It is not there in ~/Library

Comment: @Milen `~/Library/Services`, and you can always `Command+Click` a document's name (in this case the service in Automator) to show the full path in a popup menu.