# Possible in bash? Turning command expansion into arguments

Tags: command-line, bash

Are the only options for bash command expansion:

- unquoted `$(..)` whose output is always parsed with dumb string splitting, or
- quoted `"$(..)"` whose output is always passed along as a unit?

I'm trying to replicate in bash a fish shell function I created for use on Mac OS. My fish function `selection` https://superuser.com/a/1165855 takes the selection in the frontmost window and outputs the paths for use in command substitution like `ls -l (selection)`. I was hoping to achieve the same thing in bash perhaps as `ls -l $(selection)`.

I thought it was a matter of quoting and so tried passing linefeed-delimited paths to bash's `printf "%q "`. However I found that no matter what quoting I wrapped the command substitution output in, it was getting divided at whitespace.

Simplified example:

```
$ touch file\ a file\ b
$ ls $( echo "file\ a file\ b" ) # want expansion equiv to: ls 'file a' 'file b'
ls: a: No such file or directory
ls: b: No such file or directory
ls: file\: No such file or directory
ls: file\: No such file or directory
```

It wouldn't be the end of the world if I had to use quoted command substitution like `ls -l "$(selection)"` but doing that the command's output never gets split, nevermind observing my careful quoting. Is the old backtick syntax any different?

Funny, bash, you've got a lot of features. Has nobody though to allow `cmda $(cmdb-that-generates-parameters-for-cmda)`? Or does a bash user just avoid any spaces or symbols in filenames (like an animal) to make everything easy? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're multiple ways to do what you want.
By default `bash` using [whitespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) as default separator, but you can easily override this using `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) or use different technique such as enumeration. Below are few examples that first come to mind.

## Variant#1

Using special internal variable `IFS` (Internal Field Separator)

```
#!/bin/bash

touch 'file a' 'file b'

# Set IFS to new line as a separator
IFS='
'
ls -la $( echo 'file a'; echo 'file b' )
```

## Variant#2

Using `for` loop

```
#!/bin/bash

touch 'file a' 'file b'
for variable in 'file a' 'file b';do
  ls -la "${variable}"
done
```

## Variant#3

Using `for` loop from predefined values

```
#!/bin/bash

MultiArgs='
arg 0 1
arg 0  2
arg 0   3
arg 0    N
'

# Using only new line as a separator
IFS='
'

for variable in ${MultiArgs};do
  touch "${variable}"
  ls -la "${variable}"
done
```

## Variant#4

Using `~` (tilda) as separator

```
#!/bin/bash

MultiArgs='arg 0 1~arg 0 2~arg0 3~ar g 0 N' # Arguments with spaces

IFS='~'
for file in ${MultiArgs};do
 touch "${file}"
 ls -la "${file}";
done
```

> Is the old backtick syntax any different?

No, it is the same but backticks has some limitation that `$()` doesn't.

> Or does a bash user just avoid any spaces or symbols in filenames (like an animal) to make everything easy?

No, it is Ok to use spaces in filenames as far as one would use correct quoting.

As about `$(cmdb-that-generates-parameters-for-cmda)`

```
#!/bin/bash

# first command generate text for `sed` command that replacing . to ###
echo $( for i in {1..5}; do echo "${i} space .";done | sed 's/\./###/g' )

#############################################
# Another example: $() inside of another $()
for i in {1..5}; do touch "${i} x.file";done # Prepare some files with spaces in filenames

IFS='
'
echo "$( ls -la $(for i in ls *.file; do echo "$i"; done))"
```

---

If you'd like to pass all parameters in one single line to feed your program `transcode` you can add to the end your `~/.bashrc`  file following function:

```
_tr() {
  local debug
  debug=1
  [ $debug -eq 1 ] && {
    echo "Number of Arguments: $#"
    echo "Arguments: $@"
  }

  transcode "$@"
}
```

and call this function from command line like that:

```
eval _tr $(echo "$out")
```

Where variable `out` must be like that: `out="'file a' 'file b'"`.
If would type filenames manually then call to `_tr` function might looks like:

```
eval _tr $(echo "'file a' 'file b'")
```

If you would use some external script in place of `$()` than external script/program must return list of files quoted exactly like this:

```
"'file a' 'file b'"
```

Comment: change from "${i}.file" to "${i} x.file" ... what were you saying about being ok to use spaces? ;^)

Comment: And I'm looking to do something like this as a convenience from the command line, not from a script, so boilerplate like setting IFS etc is not appropriate. But thanks anyway, especially for direct answers to my specific questions

Comment: @PierreHouston Bug fixed :)))

Comment: @PierreHouston For command line operations (without making script) use variant#2, just separate commands with `;` character

Comment: Nice fast bug fix :thumbsup:. I don't see how #2 helps me at all. I (almost) literally want to type at a bash prompt: `cmda $(cmdb-that-generates-parameters-for-cmda)`, a more literal example: `transcode $(selection)`. It seems not possible, I'm going to just start using fish-shell on my work Macs.

Comment: @PierreHouston `transcode "$(for i in '1 x.file'  '2 x.file';do echo "${i}";done)"` That what I meant how to employ variant#2, list your files in place of `N x.file` but make sure you enclosed it with single quotes. You can insert your selection between **in** and first `;` as many files as you need separated by space.

Comment: Thanks @Alex but this is not in a script, this is me typing a command at the prompt and I'm looking for a convenience :^) If I have to type `transcode "$(for i in ... whatever` then fail because the syntax isn't convenient. If I have to type the names of the files, then fail because the point is to have that filled in *for me*. I *very literally* only want to type `transcode "$(selection)"` and have the `selection` function or script find the files I want (this part I can do) and output something that bash will accept as paths that can have inconvenient spaces or symbols (this bash cannot do).

Comment: @PierreHouston When you typing manually filenames that includes space in command line, all you have to do is to enclose those filenames in single quotes. As about populating filenames from function or script `selection`, - could you add some example of such function or script to your question, Im pretty sure we would find some solution, usually it is a matter of adding double quoiting like `"'some file'"` in those external scripts or functions that generates filenames.

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest Alex :^) If its a matter of quoting then in my original "file a" "file b" example with `transcode $( echo "X" )`, one could come up with some X that would end up with `transcode` getting the two parameters "file a" and "file b"`. It seems however that output from `$( )` is not fed back into bash's quote parsing but instead split at spaces. If X is `'some file'` then `transcode` gets parameters `'some` and `file'`. I should've spoken to your prev example more, I don't think "$( for i.. echo "${i}

Comment: (forgive the incomplete edit in the previous comment) The suggestion in your previous comment, `transcode "$( for i.. )"`, would demonstrate the 2nd option bash has, quoted `"$( .. )"`. It seems that any output from that is passed to `transcode` as one parameter. If this is wrong, then one should be able to make a counter-example in the form `transcode "$( echo X )"` for some X, right? So sorry if my original Q was unclear, restating: was trying to find an X so that either `transcode $( echo X )` or `transcode "$( echo X )"` will end up with `transcode` getting the parameters `file a` `file b`

Comment: @PierreHouston Sorry with delay answer, got a little busy last days. I added one more solution to my answer(in the end), I guess it is exactly what you are looking for. If you need some assistance to create external script that would feed correctly `_tr` function, then add to your question external script that you using to form list of files that includes space(s) in filenames, so we would try to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

With `xargs`:

```
echo '"file a" "file b"' | xargs ls
```

Mind the quotes. Note `xargs` is not a Bash builtin (I'm mentioning this in a context of your "Bash, you've got a lot of features").

With `eval` which is a Bash builtin:

```
eval ls $( echo '"file a" "file b"' )
```

Again, mind the quotes. This may [backfire easily](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Methods based on changing the `IFS` ([this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1353979/432690)) seem safer. On the other hand with `eval` you can even do this:

```
eval ls $( echo '"file "{a,b}' )
```

---

Unfortunately none of these is as simple as the other shell's `ls (selection)` syntax you began with. However you can simplify the syntax of any(?) solution with a custom function, e.g.:

```
_(){ "$2" | xargs "$1"; }
```

This allows you to call `_ ls selection`, if only `selection` generates input for `xargs` right. Even better, this:

```
_(){ "${@:$#}" | xargs "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"; }
```

makes `_ ls -l "file c" selection` possible. I guess you could create a similar function that uses the "change the `IFS`" method from another answer.

Still, this is not as flexible and elegant as fish's `ls (selection)`. I expect you can do `ls (selection1) (selection2)` in fish; the above `_` function doesn't cover this case.

On the other hand `eval ls $(selection1) $(selection2)` may work if `selection1` and `selection2` return strings *sanitized* with proper quoting and/or escaping. If an attacker can make you select a file named `; rm -rf ~/;` you'd better sanitize well; or not use `eval` in the first place.

Comment: Right, I wasn't speaking of just bash, but command-line usability when using bash shell in a terminal app on a unix-y system, specifically Mac OS in my case. So all signs point to No, bash just cannot do this. Thanks.

Comment: meant to say.. bash cannot do this without using `eval`.